# Sum values from two tables ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, aggregate

I want two values, in two different tables, to be used as a total in a third table.

For instance:

1. Table `accommodation` and `flight`
2. Add value from `acc_price` with value from `flight_price`
3. Add those values up to be used in table reservation `subtotal`

**Things I've tried;**

```
SELECT  F.FLI_PRICE + AC.ACC_PRICEPN
INTO    R.SUBTOTAL
FROM    HOLIDAY_RESERVATION R, FLIGHT F, ACCOMMODATION AC;
```

**UPDATE**

I wish to add the code from Leigh into a trigger, I tried the following but got a mutation error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HR_SUBTOTAL
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON HOLIDAY_RESERVATION
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE HOLIDAY_RESERVATION R SET SUBTOTAL = 
   NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.IN_FLIGHT_ID), 0) +
   NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.OUT_FLIGHT_ID), 0) +
   NVL((SELECT AC.ACC_PRICEPN FROM ACCOMMODATION AC WHERE AC.ACC_ID = R.ACC_ID), 0);
END;
/

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table LATIN.HOLIDAY_RESERVATION is mutating, trigger/f
ORA-06512: at "LATIN.HR_SUBTOTAL", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'LATIN.HR_SUBTOTAL'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update a column using a sum of values from other tables that may have nulls, do something like this:

```
UPDATE Holiday_Reservation R SET Subtotal = 
   NVL((SELECT F.Fli_Price FROM Flight F WHERE F.Fli_ID = R.In_Flight_ID), 0) +
   NVL((SELECT F.Fli_Price FROM Flight F WHERE F.Fli_ID = R.Out_Flight_ID), 0) +
   NVL((SELECT AC.Acc_PricePn FROM Accommodation AC WHERE AC.Acc_ID = R.Acc_ID), 0);
```

In a trigger this would look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HR_SUBTOTAL
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON HOLIDAY_RESERVATION
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SELECT 
      NVL((SELECT F.Fli_Price FROM Flight F WHERE F.Fli_ID = :new.In_Flight_ID), 0) +
      NVL((SELECT F.Fli_Price FROM Flight F WHERE F.Fli_ID = :new.Out_Flight_ID), 0) +
      NVL((SELECT AC.Acc_PricePn FROM Accomodation AC WHERE AC.Acc_ID = :new.Acc_ID), 0)
      INTO :new.Subtotal
   FROM dual;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't explain what is the join relationship between the tables...

I propose the following:

```
select F.key_col, F_price + AC_price as total_price
FROM
    (SELECT key_col, sum(F.FLI_PRICE) as F_price
    from FLIGHT F
    group by key_col) as F
  inner join 
    (SELECT key_col, sum(AC.ACC_PRICEPN) as AC_price
    from ACCOMMODATION AC
    group by key_col) as AC 
  on F.key_col = AC.key_col
```

Add any other tables as you wish.
If you want to filter and have better performance, please provide more information.